# Got an error in unity3d with ima code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity error is saying :

```
Assets/Scenes/Scripts/Items/CreateNewScroll.cs(23,33): error CS0117: `CreateNewScroll' does not contain a definition for `SpellEffectID'
```

Filename and class name seem okay.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateNewScroll : MonoBehaviour {

    private BaseScroll newScroll;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CreateScroll();
        Debug.Log (newScroll.ItemName);
        Debug.Log (newScroll.ItemDescription);
        Debug.Log (newScroll.ItemID.ToString());
        Debug.Log (newScroll.spellEffectID.ToString());

    }

    private void CreateScroll(){
        newScroll = new BaseScroll();
        newScroll.ItemName = "Scroll";
        newScroll.ItemDescription = "This is a powerfull scroll!";
        newScroll.ItemID = Random.Range(1,101);
        CreateNewScroll.SpellEffectID = Random.Range(500,1001);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line

```
CreateNewScroll.SpellEffectID = Random.Range(500,1001);
```

You're referring to what would be a static field on the `CreateNewScroll` class, which does not exist in the code provided. This is because you refer to the class directly, rather than a specific object of the class.

Going by the rest of the function, it looks that should be in the `newScroll.spellEffectID` field as per

```
private void CreateScroll(){
    newScroll = new BaseScroll();
    newScroll.ItemName = "Scroll";
    newScroll.ItemDescription = "This is a powerfull scroll!";
    newScroll.ItemID = Random.Range(1,101);
    newScroll.spellEffectID = Random.Range(500,1001);
}
```